# Why doesn't "prompt: 'none'" work well in Google SignIn?

Tags: google-signin, google-openidconnect

I wrote some codes to build web app using Google SignIn.
First, initiallize API platform,

```
gAuth = gapi.auth2.init( {
    client_id: gAuthClientId,
    fetch_basic_profile: false,
    scope: gAuthScope
} );
```

and make user to sign in.

```
gAuth.signIn({
    prompt: 'none'
});
```

In this code, I want to skip auth popup for (already) signed in user, and I follow the [reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) in developer document:

> **prompt:** Specifies whether to prompt the user for re-authentication. See OpenID Connect Request Parameters. Optional.

and [parameter document](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#RequestParameters) which is shown in document above.

> **prompt**
>   OPTIONAL. Space-delimited, case-sensitive list of ASCII string values that specifies whether the Authorization Server prompts the End-User for reauthentication and consent. The defined values are:
>   **none**
>   The Authorization Server MUST NOT display any authentication or consent user interface pages. An error is returned if an End-User is not already authenticated or the Client does not have pre-configured consent for the requested Claims or does not fulfill other conditions for processing the request. The error code will typically be login_required, interaction_required. This can be used as a method to check for existing authentication and/or consent.

but it doesn't works well. Actually, for signed in user, the API shows empty popup once, and closes it immediately. When I do this phase automatically, it was blocked browser.

Why does it happen? What shoud I do to avoid popup for signed in users?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you find a solution ?